# How to stop angular websocket connection from opening after a timeout value

Tags: angular, websocket, angular6

I'm using angular websocket connection to send and receive data from the server. When I'm trying to open a websocket connection, it sometimes takes over 10sec to open the connection. I need to stop opening the connection after 10sec, if the connection is not yet open. Then I should be able to stop the current connection and inform the client about the connection termination.
I cannot use websocket.close() method, as the connection is not yet opened. Is there any other way to terminate the connection opening request?
My sample code used is as below:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(url);
setTimeout(() => {
    if (ws.readyState == 0) { 
        // Need some code here to terminate connection request
    }
}, 5000);
```

My websocket.service.ts code is as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

    constructor() { }
    private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;
    public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
        if (!this.subject) {
            this.subject = this.create(url);
            console.log('Successfully connected: ' + url);
        }
        return this.subject;
    }

    private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {

        const ws = new WebSocket(url);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (ws.readyState == 0) { 

            }
        }, 5000);


        const observable =   
        Rx.Observable.create((obs:Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {

            ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
            return ws.close.bind(ws);
        });
        const observer = {
            next: (data: Object) => {
                if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            }
        };
        return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
    }
}
```